# No sound from the external monitor (HDMI)

Tags: sound, hdmi

I have Ubuntu 16.04 on carbon x1 1st gen and there is no volume from the HDMI of the external monitor (LG). The cable is DisplayPort to HDMI. The audio device is Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04).

I see HDMI/DisplayPort in the sound settings inside unity-control-center sounds but switching to it doesn't solve it.

When I open pavucontrol, under playback I see the audio bar moving since i have something running on mpv. Under output devices I see Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI) and the 'port' dropdown only have one option: HDMI/DisplayPort (plugged in).

Any tips are welcome!

Here are a few commands that might be helpful to troubleshoot the issue:

lsb_release -a

`No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial`

uname -a

`Linux oren 4.4.0-93-generic #116-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 21:17:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

aplay -l

`**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VC Analog [ALC269VC Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0`

amixer

`Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Beep',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 63
  Front Left: Capture 52 [83%] [21.75dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 52 [83%] [21.75dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Auto-Mute Mode',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Enabled'
Simple mixer control 'Digital',0
  Capabilities: cvolume
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 120
  Front Left: Capture 89 [74%] [14.50dB]
  Front Right: Capture 89 [74%] [14.50dB]
Simple mixer control 'Internal Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Loopback Mixing',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Enabled'`

lsmod | grep ^snd

`snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          40960  3
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    81920  18 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,thinkpad_acpi,snd_seq_device`

cat /proc/asound/card*/codec*

`Codec: Realtek ALC269VC
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x10ec0269
Subsystem Id: 0x17aa21f9
Revision Id: 0x100203
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x5f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 CLKSTOP EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
GPIO: io=2, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=1, wake=0
  IO[0]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[1]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
Node 0x02 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x41d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="ALC269VC Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x57, nsteps=0x57, stepsize=0x02, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x57 0x57]
  Converter: stream=5, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x03 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x41d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Speaker Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x57, nsteps=0x57, stepsize=0x02, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x57 0x57]
  Converter: stream=5, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x04 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x05 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x06 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x611: Stereo Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x5f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
Node 0x07 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x08 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10051b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x17, nsteps=0x3f, stepsize=0x02, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x97 0x97]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
  Connection: 1
     0x23
Node 0x09 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10051b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="ALC269VC Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x17, nsteps=0x3f, stepsize=0x02, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x34 0x34]
  Converter: stream=1, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x22
Node 0x0a [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x0b [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Mic Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Mic Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Beep Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=4, ofs=0
  Control: name="Beep Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=4, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x17, nsteps=0x1f, stepsize=0x05, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 5
     0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1d
Node 0x0c [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x00 0x00]
  Connection: 2
     0x02 0x0b
Node 0x0d [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x00 0x00]
  Connection: 2
     0x03 0x0b
Node 0x0e [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x0f [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010a: Mono Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00] [0x80]
  Connection: 2
     0x02 0x0b
Node 0x10 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x11 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x12 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40040b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Internal Mic Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x90a60140: [Fixed] Mic at Int N/A
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x4, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x13 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x14 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Speaker Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00010014: OUT EAPD Detect
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x90170110: [Fixed] Speaker at Int N/A
    Conn = Analog, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x0c 0x0d*
Node 0x15 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x0001001c: OUT HP EAPD Detect
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x03211020: [Jack] HP Out at Ext Left
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0x2, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0xc0: OUT HP
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
  Connection: 2
     0x0c* 0x0d
Node 0x16 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x17 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40050c: Mono Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80]
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
  Connection: 1
     0x0f
Node 0x18 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Control: name="Mic Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x00003734: IN OUT Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  Pin Default 0x03a11830: [Jack] Mic at Ext Left
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x24: IN VREF_80
  Unsolicited: tag=02, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
  Connection: 2
     0x0c* 0x0d
Node 0x19 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x00003734: IN OUT Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
  Connection: 2
     0x0c* 0x0d
Node 0x1a [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0000373c: IN OUT HP Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
  Connection: 2
     0x0c* 0x0d
Node 0x1b [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x00003734: IN OUT Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80 100
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
  Connection: 2
     0x0c* 0x0d
Node 0x1c [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x1d [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400400: Mono
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x40138205: [N/A] Speaker at Ext N/A
    Conn = ATAPI, Color = Purple
    DefAssociation = 0x0, Sequence = 0x5
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
Node 0x1e [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400781: Stereo Digital
  Pincap 0x00000014: OUT Detect
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
  Connection: 1
     0x06
Node 0x1f [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x20 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00040: Mono
  Processing caps: benign=0, ncoeff=37
Node 0x21 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x22 [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x00 0x00]
  Connection: 7
     0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1d 0x0b 0x12
Node 0x23 [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 6
     0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1d 0x0b
Codec: Intel PantherPoint HDMI
Address: 3
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 0)
Vendor Id: 0x80862806
Subsystem Id: 0x80860101
Revision Id: 0x100000
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x0]:
    bits [0x0]:
    formats [0x0]:
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D3 CLKSTOP EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0, Clock-stop-OK
GPIO: io=0, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=0, wake=0
Node 0x02 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1e]: 16 20 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x03 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1e]: 16 20 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x04 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1e]: 16 20 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x05 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="ELD", index=0, device=3
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x18560010: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x02
Node 0x06 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x80]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x58560020: [N/A] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x2, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x03
Node 0x07 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x80]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x58560030: [N/A] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x04
Node 0x08 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono`

Comment: is pulse audio control set to send the audio to the HDMI ?

Comment: Is the monitor voume up?

Comment: The monitor volume is up. @ravery, how to check the pulse audio control?

Comment: in you're menu there should be pulse audio volume control. under the playback tab it shows programs producing sound and to which device it is being routed to.

Comment: under 'playback' i see mpv media player and the name of the video currently playing. under 'output devices' i see built-in audio digital stereo (hdmi). port HDMI/DIsplayPort (plugged in). under both tabs I see the audio indicator moving up and down. Here are 2 screenshots: http://imgur.com/a/WVRoz

Comment: did you ever fix this? I'm having the same problem, it used to work fine suddenly it doesn't

Comment: no Alb, I didn't fix it.